# Typescript: Object.assign(this, data) not working as expected

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a constructor on my class where I don't need to manually type out every field like so:

```
this.x = data.x;
this.y = data.y;
```

Instead I'd like to assign all fields at once from a single object. I found examples online that suggested the following method:

```
export class GameState {
    x: number;
    y: number;
 
    constructor(fields: GameState) {
        Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
}
```

However my code won't compile. I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'x' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
Property 'y' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

Is this a viable approach and if so what am I missing?

If not, what's a better approach?

Comment: That's not how constructors work ;)

Comment: @DorinBaba That's exactly how constructor works :)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Object.assign()* should work like you want, setting all the member variables from the constructor argument.  Since the compiler can't tell that the member variables will be assigned by *Object.assign()*, use a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) operator with the member properties.

The non-null assertion operator exists for this very reason - to tell the type-checker that those values won't be null when it can't make the determination.

```
class GameState {
    x!: number;
    y!: number;
 
    constructor(fields: GameState) {
        Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically this is a "defnite assignment" assertion operator. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303411/567493

Answer (score 2):

The error looks ambiguous, but typescript is just telling you that `x` and `y` may not be defined after one constructs a `GameState` object.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Make `x` and `y` optional

  ```
  export class GameState {
    x?: number;
    y?: number;

    constructor(fields: GameState) {
      Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
  }
  ```
- Assign `x` and `y` default values

  ```
  export class GameState {
    x: number = NaN;
    y: number = NaN;

    constructor(fields: GameState) {
      Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
  }
  ```

A third option exists, and I usually use this when I write classes in Typescript:

```
export class GameState {
    constructor(public x: number = NaN, public y: number = NaN) {}
}
```

There! Now `x` and `y` can be directly assigned a value from the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using latest version of typescript, and it is strict checking your variables, as x & y are not being initialized anywhere it is throwing errors. There can be 3 ways to fix your problem

1. [Strict Property Initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) -> Go to **tsconfig.json** and add `"strictPropertyInitialization": false`. This will prevent such errors.
2. Initialize x & y or all such variables or use [Definite Assignment Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) to tell typescript that these variables wont be run at runtime.
3. If you are using vscode, change version of ts.

your code is working fine with me  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-znznha?file=index.ts)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HEUFtgDKMKMwcA3gFBw1wgBccAdgK64BGwUA3NbQJ6NWHLrzh8aCCEzQwoLBDGgAKAGYBLYEgAmaRjnxESwAJQUJtGgHl2AK2CKAdOjTqA5k2UwAFurQAaOA0tXRMxWgBfSiigA

Comment: if you go to TS Config dropdown on top. Under the Type Checking settings uncheck `strictPropertyInitialization` checkbox.  The errors will be gone.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HEUFtgDKMKMwcA3gFBw1wgBccAdgK64BGwUA3NbQJ6NWHLrzh8aCCEzQwoLBDGgAKAGYBLYEgAmaRjnxESwAJQUJtGgHl2AK2CKAdOjTqA5k2UwAFurQAaOA0tXRMxWgBfSiigA